# How To Keep Checking For Something Without a Timer?

Tags: c#, user-interface, mouseevent

I need to be able to check if the mouse is within a certain area on the form continuously.  I want to be able to do this without the use of a timer, though.  How would I go about doing this?

I'm using C# btw.

Comment: You should listen to mouse events and do the verification every time the mouse moves.

Comment: You might want to explain why you don't want to use a timer. I think a timer is perfect in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried attaching a handler to the [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event, and checking on each movement?

Answer (score 3):

If the area is a screen control, you can use `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `MouseHover` and `MouseMove` events.

Comment: So if I'm trying to check if the mouse is inside a rectangle by the name of "rect", I would use something like: if(rect.Contains(MouseEnter))

Answer (score 1):

I think the mouse events suggested by others is the best solution, but as another alternative to timers, you could write a small function to check the mouse and then keep invoking it on your main window dispatcher with an "application idle" priority. This will continuously run your check without freezing the UI.
Again, hooking into the mousemove event is still a cleaner solution, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If hooking the MouseMove event triggers too often - or if you want to avoid hooking that event on every form, consider hooking the [Application.Idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event instead.

This event fires every time the application is about to go idle - all pending messages (including repaints) have been processed and there's nothing left to do. In most WinForms applications, this happens several times a second, providing a good way to do "just in time" processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define events over that area.

Use `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` together to decide if mouse is in this area or not !

`OnMouseEnter` until `OnMouseLeave` means that mouse is still in that area.